# Cannot view source HTML on Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I am unable to view the HTML content of web pages when I view source in Google Chrome's dev tools. For example, if I view the source of https://stackoverflow.com/help, the only content I can see is as follows.

```
<script>
    $('#herobox li').click(function () {
        StackExchange.using("gps", function () {
            StackExchange.gps.track("aboutpage.click", { aboutclick_location: "hero" }, true);
        });

        window.location.href = '/about';
    });
    $('#tell-me-more').click(function () {
        StackExchange.using("gps", function () {
            StackExchange.gps.track("aboutpage.click", { aboutclick_location: "hero" }, true);
        });
    });
    $('#herobox #close').click(function () {
        StackExchange.using("gps", function () {
            StackExchange.gps.track("hero.action", { hero_action_type: "minimize" }, true);
        });
        $.cookie("hero", "mini", { path: "/" });
        $.ajax({
            url: "/hero-mini",
            success: function (data) {
                $("#herobox").fadeOut("fast", function () {
                    $("#herobox").replaceWith(data);
                    $("#herobox-mini").fadeIn("fast");
                });
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
</script>
```

I'm not sure if I've inadvertently changed a setting in Chrome, but any help would be greatly appreciated.

I'm using chrome Version 29.0.1547.76.
I have disabled all extensions.
I tried this using a new profile with the same effect.
I'm not behind a proxy.

Comment: Tried a new Chrome profile? What version of Chrome are you using? Did you install any extensions? Are you seeing `view-source:stackoverflow.com/help` in the browser? Are you behind a proxy? Some more background info would help...

Comment: I've added more information to the question and also altered a misleading statement. The problem arises when I view source in dev tools, not click 'View Page Source' after right-clicking on the page. When I do the latter I can see the source with no problems.

Comment: Either a feature (the only displayed tags are `<script>`-tags) or a bug. Look for a bug at https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues or report a new one if you cannot find it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you open the DevTools after loading the page, the content of the items listed on the Resources tab may not be populated. This is also true of network requests on the Network tab. To see the fully populated resources on the Resources tab, first open the DevTools, then refresh the page, or navigate to the desired page with the DevTools open. Now select the html resource and it should be populated.